# Cant convert String to date in android

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
final Object ret = task.getResult().get("ReturnExpiry");
returndate = String.valueOf(ret);
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                        try {
                            date = format.parse(returndate);
Log.e("date",String.valueOf(date));
                        } catch (ParseException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

I am getting the error as

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Thu Jun 21 04:33:58 GMT+00:00 2018"
06-14 10:02:12.681 18943-18943/com.bodaty.samyata.samyata W/System.err:     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:362)
```

why I am getting error like this when I am trying to parse ....
if I use code as below my app is crashing with parse error.....can anyone help me please

```
java.util.Date dt = new java.util.Date(returndate);
```

Comment: is your _"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"_ is correct? make sure this is the format that you are getting in `returndate`  or just post the date which you are passing.. i will check

Comment: your date format does not match your date. Read the `SimpleDateFormat` documentation to build pattern for your date

Answer (score 0):

Your data doesn't match your pattern.  update your pattern like this

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
        Date date = null;
        try{
            date  = sdf.parse("Thu Jun 21 04:33:58 GMT+00:00 2018");
        }catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace(); }
        System.out.println("check..." + date;
```

Hope it will solve your problem